# Avro rpc only import records not rpc methods

Tags: grpc, avro

I am working with legacy avdl definitions for rpc. I am creating a new one for purpose and importing records from another avdl definition. Is there a way to only import records not the rpc service definitions since mavan avro plugins generate the method stubs as well in my new class which I dont want